Remove or removed
Which sentence is correct?
"Did you know we also removed small trees?"
"Did you know we also remove small trees?"
Trying to advertise that my company removes small trees. Can't figure out which one to use.

Hi. Both are grammatically correct. Which do you think would suit the context best?  Here's a hint: Present tense: to state facts/talk about things which are done habitually. Past tense: to talk about things which happened in the past and which are over/finished.

The point here (as so often) is it's not about right/wrong. It's about meaning. Do you want to describe past actions or present actions? Choose the tense that matches that answer.

As your company still provides this service, we use the present tense:

Did you know we also remove small trees?

The past tense is less likely unless we want to illustrate this skill through past projects:
Did you know in some of our previous shrub removal projects, we also removed the (or 'some') small trees at reasonable additional cost?

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but they mean different things.
If you say "removed", that is past tense. Perhaps you removed small trees at some specific time in the past. Like, "In April we removed 10 small trees from the lot of Mr Jones." Or you used to be in the business of removing small trees, but you no longer provide this service.
What I think you want to say here is "remove", present tense. It is a service that you provide now.
